# Why can't I flag comments on election nominations?

Tags: support, flags, comments, moderator-election

I just checked out https://stackoverflow.com/election/6 and saw a lot of nonsense comments ("ah! Thanks for pointing out the typo.", "Best Luck buddy!", etc.). Why can't I flag them - being as unconstructive as any other unconstructive comment on other sites (I haven't found another where I can't flag, so I assume is nomination-site specific)?

A screenshot to show that the comments can't be flagged (no example of noisy comments (check out the link for that):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: I wouldn't really be too concerned about "chatty" comments on election posts (they're not really part of the usual Q/A format, after all), but it would be nice to have the option of flagging spam/offensive comments there.

Comment: Comment actions are disabled on the nominations as they aren't questions and answers that are being commented on, so the same rules don't apply. Whether or not moderators still have an ability to clean up comments is a different matter, but i'd ignore it.

Comment: I think your screenshot is of the wrong nomination.

Comment: Understood. Still the nominations are just impossible to read regarding the fact that some comments are really sharp and therefore make it necessary to read comments...

Comment: I wonder if all the noisy comments is *because* upvoting of comments has been disabled along with flagging...

Comment: see [Can \*too\* upvote comments under an election nomination](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252916/165773) at MSE: "Voting for comments has been disabled during the nomination phase for now. We want to make sure that we are at consistent when it comes to elections."

Comment: I assume it has something to do with comments being fairly intangible, with loose requirements to (apparently permanently) delete them -- letting people flag could allow motivated nefarious individuals to remove comments to strategically support their own views. `<\paranoia>`